# Electron and Typescript: How do I handle modules at runtime correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, electron

I'm writing an Electron desktop application in Typescript. After compilation, the project organization looks something like this:

- dist

  - html

    - index.html
  - scripts

    - ApplicationView.js
    - ApplicationViewModel.js

In `index.html` I have this script tag:

```html
<script src="../scripts/Application.js"></script>
```

All my files are compiled from Typescript to ES2015 (targeting ES6 and using ES6 modules) and transpiled by Babel to ES5. `ApplicationView.ts` looks like this:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/main.d.ts" />

import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as ko from "knockout";
import ApplicationViewModel from "./ApplicationViewModel";

$(document).ready(() => {
    ko.applyBindings(new ApplicationViewModel("Hello!"));
});
```

Here's the contents of `ApplicationViewModel.ts`:

```js
import * as ko from "knockout";

export default class ApplicationViewModel {
    public greeting: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(greeting: string) {
        this.greeting = ko.observable(greeting);
    }
}
```

Electron throws an error saying it can't find the module `./ApplicationViewModel`. However, in the debugger console, I can successfully import the module with:

```
require("../scripts/ApplicationViewModel");
```

So, what's wrong is obvious. The script tag effectively copies the contents of `Application.js` into the HTML file, changing the context for the module's relative path. My question is **what should I really be doing?**

I've seen the use of `require.js` in the script tag. But Electron runs on Node.js. If this is the right way to handle my problem, why then would I need another module loader? How would I make sure the two play nice?

Comment: Can you show us what's inside `ApplicationViewModel.js` ? Pretty sure it's a problem with `export default` or something

Comment: I've edited my question to include that file's contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Pretty simple actually. I replaced the `<script>` tag in the HTML file with this:

```
<script>
    require("../scripts/ApplicationView");
</script>
```

Works like a charm! Now I just need to figure out why JQuery isn't working properly...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the es5 and the es6 ways to export modules:

```
module.exports =  ApplicationViewModel; // ES5
export default ApplicationViewModel; // ES6
```

Comment: Yeah, I was targeting CommonJS. Tried switching to target ES6, but I've got the same problem. Not sure I follow what you're saying is wrong. My Typescript is purposefully targeting ES6, because I want to use async/await. Then Babel is supposed to transpile that to ES5. Nowhere am I using ES5 style exports in the actual source code; that's a result of transpilation.